# Highlight div when using <a href="#goToDiv">

Tags: css

I have a tag `<a href="#myDiv">` which links to `<div id="myDiv">`...
If I paste this link to browser, like: `index.htm#myDiv` it goes directly to `myDiv`. Is it possible to set CSS which will highlight `myDiv` when I do this operation?

Comment: yes this is possible! did you try something yet? got some code? make a jsfiddle!

Comment: Using javascript this is very possible. Try something out and we can help you tidy it up.

Comment: I tried :actvie selector. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [:target pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget):

```
:target {
 /* Your rules here for the myDiv element */
}
```

You could also narrow the selector further if you needed, like `#myDiv:target`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fzc6afrb/)**